# find using multiple joins in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

I try to build a soccer manager game using rails and I'm stuck with the rails association.

```
team table
  ...

history table
  team_id
  saison_id

saison table
  league_id
  league table
  ...
```

I want to find all the team for one league.

```
class History < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :saison
  belongs_to :team
end

class Saison < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :histories
  has_many :teams, :through => :histories
  belongs_to :league
end

class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :saisons 
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Bases
  has_many :histories
  has_many :saisons, :through => :histories
end
```

I want to do something like (in the show method of the league controller) :

```
@team = Team.find(:all, :include => [:saisons => :histories, :leagues => :saisons], 
          :conditions => ["leagues.id = ?", params[:id]])
```

but it does not work.

The SQL query :

```
SELECT Team.* 
FROM   Team, Saison, History, League  
WHERE  History.Team_ID = Team.ID AND 
       History.Saison_ID = Saison.ID AND 
       Saison.League_ID = League.ID
```

this query return all the team for one saison...but I do not achieve to make it work for league

```
@division = Team.find(:all, :include => [:saisons => :histories],
                                :conditions =>["saisons.id =?",params[:id]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the league controller, in the show method, I try something like

```
 @team = Equipe.find(:all, :include => [:saisons => :history],
                                :conditions =>["saisons.league_id =?",params[:id]])
```

I would include the league in the find statement to have all its attributes (name for instance) in the same result tab.

I know I can those information about league in another query, but it is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are naming your tables and models in another language, then it's much more likely that you won't follow Rails' naming conventions (but it can happen with English too!).

Anyway, if the plural of a certain word doesn't end with an S, you have to go to the file `inflections.rb` located in `your_app/config/initializers` and add there the plural of certain words. This is just as an example:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'merchandise', 'merchandising'
end
```

As for your particular question, I'm not sure if I understand, but you want ALL the teams of a season? That's easy, it's just:

```
@saison_teams = saison.teams
```

You then you want all the teams of a division but you haven't told us what a division is!

Comment: OH...I want all the team for one league

Comment: Well, you can iterate through the teams like this, but it isn't very efficient: `League.saisons.each do |saison| puts saison.teams end`

Comment: yes but I'd rather use and find the best :include statement to get the joins between league and saison in my ifnd statement, in order to learn

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got to this point, but your naming conventions are wrong for a Rails application.

Let's look at History.
Your model should be called "History".
The first line of app/models/history.rb would be:
`class History < ActiveRecord::Base`

The table generated in your database should be called "histories".

Then when you are setting up your associations, you need to pay attention to pluralization.

`has_many` is always followed by a pluralized word.
`belongs_to` is always followed by a singular word.

The Saison associations should look like this:

```
class Saison < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :histories
  has_many :teams, :through => :histories
  belongs_to :league
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My database is wrotten in french and I translate some fields in english, but it seems that I made translation mistake. I edit mu thread regarding to what you said. thanks